# What's the point of using [object instance].__self__?

Tags: python

I was checking the code of the toolz library's [`groupby` function](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/blob/e9bc1e150b7b1ea1bec300a55382ed564b215f41/toolz/itertoolz.py#L72-L105) in Python and I found this:

```py
def groupby(key, seq):
    """ Group a collection by a key function
    """
    if not callable(key):
        key = getter(key)
    d = collections.defaultdict(lambda: [].append)
    for item in seq:
        d[key(item)](item)
    rv = {}
    for k, v in d.items():
        rv[k] = v.__self__
    return rv
```

Is there any reason to use `rv[k] = v.__self__` instead of `rv[k] = v`?

Comment: I believe it is referring to all the individual attributes of 'itself'. Using the __self__ collects all unique values of the individual object

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__self__#index-32, under *"Instance methods"*…

Comment: `d` is a mapping of key to the `append` method of the lists created by the lambda expression, so `rv[k] = v.__self__` is building a mapping of key to the actual list. There's context on why this somewhat baffling implementation was used (**TL;DR**: speed) [here](https://github.com/pytoolz/toolz/pull/179).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is a somewhat confusing trick to save a small amount of time:

We are creating a `defaultdict` with a factory function that returns a bound `append` method of a new list instance with `[].append`. Then we can just do `d[key(item)](item)` instead of `d[key(item)].append(item)` like we would have if we create a `defaultdict` that contains lists. If we don't lookup `append` everytime, we gain a small amount of time.

But now the `dict` contains bound methods instead of the lists, so we have to get the original list instance back via `__self__`.

[`__self__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__self__#index-36) is an attribute described for [instance methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__self__#index-32) that returns the original instance. You can verify that with this for example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> a.append.__self__ is a
True
```

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode I stand by that. It is not the most clear possible code that could be used here (but it also isn't the most confusing variation they could have chosen). IMO, anything that warrants a nonterrible question on SO to just explain it could be classified as confusing.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. Confusing doesn't mean incomprehensible. It just means you have to look a couple oh times to understand what they did, and a couple more times to understand why.

Comment: Hmm, do be honest I think the question rather *is* somewhat terrible. It asks "Is there any reason to use X instead of Y?", and if they had simply *tried* Y, they would've seen that it gives a bad result.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Well it was pretty obvious to me. But I can live with the "somewhat", so +1 now :-)

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Because you have lots of experience which python. It was also pretty obvious for me, but apparently not for everyone.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. I had to look up `__self__`, having never used it before. Once I did it was trivial, and likely will remain so in the future.  It's a matter of experience.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode. We both chose adjectives starting with "con".

Comment: @MadPhysicist I agree that 'convoluted' is probably a better choice, since it slightly less strong that confusing.

Answer (score 18):

This is a somewhat convoluted, but possibly more efficient approach to creating and using a `defaultdict` of lists.

First, remember that the default item is `lambda: [].append`. This means create a new list, and store a bound `append` method in the dictionary. This saves you a method bind on every further append to the same key, and the garbage collect that follows. For example, the following more standard approach is less efficient:

```
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for item in seq:
    d[key(item)].append(item)
```

The problem then becomes how to get the original lists back out of the dictionary, since the reference is not stored explicitly. Luckily, bound methods have a `__self__` attribute which does just that. Here, `[].append.__self__` is a reference to the original `[]`.

As a side note, the last loop could be a comprehension:

```
return {k: v.__self__ for k, v in d.items()}
```

Comment: About "garbage collect": I think most if not all of the time it wouldn't get to that, would be victim to reference counting instead.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode: [Reference counting is a form (albeit a primitive one) of garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)#Reference_counting). In the CPython reference interpreter, the distinction is between the regular reference counting and cyclic GC, but both are GC. You're correct the bound methods are typically freed instantly by reference counts going to zero, rather than having to wait for the cyclic garbage collector, but bind and cleanup is still done either way (though `LOAD_METHOD`/`CALL_METHOD` sometimes avoid that in modern CPython).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, but I thought I remembered in Python terminology it's separate, and I checked the [gc documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) whose *"the collector supplements the reference counting"* rather makes it sound separate. But I now also checked the [glossary](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-garbage-collection) and the [devguide](https://devguide.python.org/garbage_collector/), both make it clear it's indeed included.