# A way in Python to agnostically append() / add() to a collection (or other receiver)?

Tags: python, python-3.8, duck-typing

Is there a way in Python to add agnostically to a collection?

Given the prevalence of duck typing I was surprised that the method to add to a `list` is `append(x)` but the method to add to a `set` is `add(x)`.

I'm writing a family of utility functions that need to build up collections and would ideally like them not to care what type is accumulating the result.  It should at least work for `list` and `set` - and ideally for other targets, as long as they know what method to implement.  Essentially, the duck type here is 'thing to which items can be added'.

In practice, these utility functions will either be passed the target object to add the results to, or - more commonly - a function that generates new instances of the target type when needed.

For example:

```
def collate(xs, n, f_make=lambda: list()):
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n < 1')
    col = f_make()
    for x in xs:
        if len(col) == n:
            yield col
            col = f_make()
        col.append(x)  # append() okay for list but not for set
    yield col
```

```
>>> list(collate(range(6), 3))
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

>>> list(collate(range(6), 4))
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]

>>> # desired result here: [{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}]
>>> list(collate(range(6), 4, f_make=lambda: set()))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/paul/proj/mbrain/src/fossil/fn.py", line 42, in collate
    col.append(x)
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Here `collate()` is just a simple example.  I expect there's already a way to achieve this 'collation' in Python.  That's not the real question here.

I'm currently using Python 3.8.5.

Comment: `MutableSet` and `MutableSequence` are different [ABCs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) with different semantics, it doesn't make sense to use the same methods. With sequences you're putting a new value at the end, with sets they're either in or not. Also adding to a set is idempotent, whereas appending to a sequence is not.

Comment: Have your function take a callback parameter that is called to add an item.  Pass it `theList.append` or `theSet.add`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, understood.  Nevertheless, there's nothing wrong IMHO with the concept of a type that has the trait of accumulating elements: be it a `list`, a `set`, a queue of some sort, or even something that outputs each item when received.  In Java you get the first two via `Collection.add()`.  If that's not an abstraction provided in Python, that's fine - the question becomes what's the best workaround.

Comment: @jasonharper I did think of passing the 'append', 'add' or other method but that would require two functions passed in: one to instantiate the new 'accumulator' (`list`, `set`, whatever) and another to provide the means to add to it.  And that opens up the possibility they mismatch.  I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Comment: It doesn't _necessarily_ require two things to be passed in, depending on what you actually wanted to do. If you required a method reference to be passed, e.g. `accumulate(range(6), [].append)` or `accumulate(range(6), set().add)` then you could `return method.__self__` (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/69270836/3001761) and get the container back. That wouldn't let you create new instances, though. Or if you wanted to just support both `MutableSet` and `MutableSequence` you could check which you received and use the relevant method.

Comment: Or you could create a protocol describing "`add`-able" and use anything that implemented it, including e.g. a set and a thin wrapper around a list that proxies `add` to `append`. _"best workaround"_ is going to depend largely on context.

Comment: @Paul Could you post your solution as an answer instead of in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returning to this later I found a better solution using `@functools.singledispatch` which is also user-extensible to additional types.

```
import functools

@functools.singledispatch
def append(xs, v):
    raise ValueError('append() not supported for ' + str(type(xs)))


@append.register
def _(xs: MutableSequence, v):
    xs.append(v)


@append.register
def _(xs: MutableSet, v):
    xs.add(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

*(This is an edited answer. Feel free to look at history for my old answer, but it was not relevant to the question)*

The `pythonic` way is to use the standard library here. Rather than manipulating lists, you can use some of the built-in functions that work on iterables more generally. As in, [itertools](https://%20https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

This function is a rough guideline for using `itertools`. It doesn't handle the case where `f_make()` isn't blank. It's also a bit dense and if you're not used to python you probably won't find this super easy to read, but it's technically probably one of the more pythonic ways to do this. I'm not certain I'd *recommend* using this, but it does a lot in a fairly small number of lines, which is sort of the point. I'm sure someone else could find a "more pythonic" approach though.

```
def collate(xs, n, f_make=list):
    result = f_make()
    for _, val in itertools.groupby(
        enumerate(xs),
        lambda i: (len(result) + i[0]) // n
    ):
        yield list(itertools.chain(result, (v[1] for v in val)))
```

**Edit 2**

Your question has been edited so I'll address the clear points in there now:

If you want a duck-typed way to add to an iterable, you should probably create your own data structure. That way, you can handle *all* iterables, and not just sets and lists. If you pass a generator in, or something that's been `sorted` or a `map` result, you probably want to be able to handle those too, right?

Here's an example of a wrapper for that kind of thing:

```
class Appender:
  def __init__(self, iterable):
    self.length = sum(1 for _ in iterable)
    self.iterable = iter(iterable)

  def append(self, new_item):
    self.length += 1
    self.iterable = itertools.chain(self.iterable, new_item)

  def __iter__(self):
    return self.iterable

  def __len__(self):
    return self.length
```

Note that you can further modify this to be a [`MutableSequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.MutableSequence) but I don't think that's strictly necessary for your use case, where you just need length. If you don't care about iterables, then I'd advise you change your question title to remove "or other receivers"

Also note that this doesn't handle `set`s like `set`s (obviously). I'm of the belief that it should be up to the caller to manage the output of a function. I personally feel that it's perfectly acceptable to require that a function caller only pass in a `MutableSequence`, and responsibility of casting it to a set should be separate. This leads to clearer and more concise functions that require less logic. If you expect a set and/or dict is going to be a common acceptance method, it's likely worth handling that separately. As was mentioned in comments to your question, these are fundamentally different data types (particularly sets which are not ordered and thus can't really be collated without first being sorted into a non-set anyway).

Comment: What I'm trying to get at is what is the Pythonic way to implement the concept of 'thing that accumulates values'?  In Java - although there's no concept of 'accumulator' (or similar) - I could at least treat (mutable) `List`s and `Set`s agnostically as both implement `Collection` which has `add(T x)`.  Aside: I'm not sure what makes you think it can loop indefinitely - but would like to.

Comment: I just ran it and there's no infinite loop so long as `xs` is not an infinite loop. My mistake - honestly didn't give it a ton of attention. This is a hard example for a general question "how do I accumulate sets and lists at the same time"? I'm editing my answer to answer your general question.

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the "pythonic" way which is probably to do it without manipulating collections :)

Comment: I find that version IMHO significantly harder to read than the solution I added to the question (it was subsequentally removed from the question).  It also doesn't produce the same results e.g. `list(collate(range(6), 2))` should be `[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]` and not `[[0, 1], [2, 3, 4, 5]]`.  Likewise, `list(collate(range(6), 1, set))` should return `[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}]` but actually returns `[[0], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]` for the above.

Comment: Probably worth noting that the specifics of the 'collating' wasn't really what the question was about; it was about how to make it (at least) list and set agnostic.

Answer (score -1):

Here's the solution I ended up with...

```
def appender(xs):
    if isinstance(xs, MutableSequence):
        f = xs.append
    elif isinstance(xs, MutableSet):
        f = xs.add
    # Could probably do better validation here...
    elif hasattr(xs, 'append'):  
        f = getattr(xs, 'append')
    else:
        raise ValueError('Don\'t know how to append to ' + str(type(xs)))
    return f


def collate(xs, n, f_make=lambda: list()):
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n < 1')
    col = f_make()
    app = appender(col)
    for x in xs:
        if len(col) == n:
            yield col
            col = f_make()
            app = appender(col)
        app(x)
    if col:
        yield col

>>> list(collate(range(6), 4, set))
[{0, 1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}]

>>> list(collate(range(6), 4, list))
[[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5]]
```

(I previously added this to the question - and it was removed.  So I'm now adding it as an answer.)

Additionally, just to clarify the intended behaviour:

```
>>> list(collate(range(6), 2, list))
[[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]

>>> list(collate(range(6), 1, set))
[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}]
```

Comment: Which is it - do you care about the intended behavior of the function or do you care about finding an agnostic way to add to a list/set or do you care about an agnostic way to add to any iterable, or do you care about a pythonic way to do this? Please revise your question to clarify. I've voted to close ATM based on the mixed messaging and the multiple questions.

Comment: Also - this is not pythonic at all (although that's at least somewhat subjective, I don't think anyone would vote this as being pythonic, so I'd suggest that you remove that requirement from your question as well)

Comment: You're right.  I shouldn't have said Pythonic but just 'is there a way in Python'.  I should note that I've only been coding extensive in Python for a few weeks.  So far, I have seen no clear indication that 'Pythonic' has any very definite meaning.  I expect that will crystalize in time.